# How to set Outlook to convert email body to file attachments before sending

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, vba, fax

In our business we do some electronic faxing, where you can send an email to [10-digit-fax-number]@[fax-service-domain], and the service faxes the email attachments (not the body). But it is sometimes handy to send what is in the body (e.g. a copied image, not a saved file). Is there a way to set Microsoft Outlook to send the body as an attachment?

Ideally, embedded images would be attached as image files, text as `.txt` or possibly `.html`. At this point I would not be very much wishing for html support. I tried sending an email as an attachment, but this fails.

If someone can suggest some VBA code, I could work with that. I do not understand Outlook enough to know how or when this setting/conversion would be done.

If the answer to my question is a direct **No** I would be happy to be able to know that. I cannot find that anyone else has wished for this, so it is unlikely.

This is my first question here, I look forward to learning the ropes!

Comment: I can recommend the commercial solution if you want.

Comment: Do you refer to the answer by @Eyal Nevo below?

Comment: No, it is an add-in for Outlook.

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing more about this @thims

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has an option in Outlook (built-in), to send a "Fax". Essentially, this would be an email sent to a service provider that is integrated with the "Fax" feature in Outlook.

When sending a new "Fax" from Outlook, Outlook will convert all of the content, body and attachments into an image file and then that image file to the fax provider.

[Here is a general page](http://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/send-fax-through-outlook-10292.html) that explains how to send a fax from Outlook.

Fair notice, I am employed by InterFAX and we also support the "Fax" feature in Outlook and you can find more information about our feature at [InterFAX web site](https://www.interfax.net/en/help/ms-office-fax-activation-new)

Comment: He asked for automated way, your answer only talks about manual, consider editing and adding the VBA script or a macro

Comment: I supposed that Automated would be the easiest way. I wish for both the feature and the ability to automate it! Will check into that built in feature.

Comment: @Eyal, I can't find this option in Outlook 2016 (Office 365). The link you provided seems to be for an earlier version. Can you give further details? I am not interested in switching fax providers, sorry. :)